# GoogleDrive File.getDescription() is null

Tags: android, google-drive-api

GoogleDrive android sdk is in use.
Insert in our App GoogleDrive Service File.
Decription on File insert a whitespace character is inserted.
But on the server to get a list of the File, came decription value null is returned.
Why a non-whitespace character null Will return?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes please, paste your code. Or even share the file.